# For handling the same exception check in through multiple methods, is it bad practice to use a handler method?

Tags: java, exception, conventions

For a simple example, I have to make the following check in 4 separate methods;

```
if (this.isEmpty()) { 
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

Would refactoring these occurrences to a single method be appropriate?

```
private void emptyQueueException() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (this.isEmpty()) { 
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

For this simple example I don't know if it matters either way, but for more complex exception handling would this be bad practice?

Comment: Reducing cut'n'pastry = good practice.

Comment: It's only going to add a single method call to the stack trace, so it should be fine.